# How to deal with method takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in functional code?

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I have made a very small function to clear a Google Calendar using the API. The API generally works.The reference code from Google Developer pages is as so:

```
service.calendars().clear('primary').execute()
```

and my function is as so:

```
def clear_gcal(service): 
    someCal = '''my_calendar_address''' 
    service.calendars().clear(someCal).execute()
    print("Some Google Cal cleared")
```

Running this with a service variable that works (I use it to add to the calendar too with no errors, I get "TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".All solutions to this I find uses self in OOP, but my code is just functional (and I prefer it that way for this), so how can I deal with this, seemingly pretty common error type? Thank You,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-87-d7bf7ff34210>", line 1, in <module> runfile('C:/Users/b017646/ExportCal/main.py', wdir='C:/Users/b017646/ExportCal')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/b017646/ExportCal/main.py", line 17, in <module> gcal.clear_gcal(service)

File "C:\Users\b017646\ExportCal\gcal.py", line 48, in clear_gcal service.calendars().clear(deaCal).execute()

TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**GregersDK**

Comment: First split it into multiple lines with one method call on each line, so you can see *which* method call is causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

You are not providing the `calendarId` parameter correctly.

#### Solution:

You should do this instead:

```
service.calendars().clear(calendarId='primary').execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [calendars().clear(calendarId=*)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.calendars.html#clear)